# Computing Maximum Concurrent Workgroups

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I was wondering if there was a standard way to programatically determine the number of maximum concurrent workgroups that can run on a GPU.

For example, on a NVIDIA card with 5 compute units (or SMs), there can be a maximum of 8 workgroups (or blocks) per compute unit, so the maximum number of workgroups that can be run concurrently is 40.

Since I can find the number of compute units with `clGetDeviceInfo`, all I need is the maximum number of workgroups that can be run on a compute unit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Max number of groups per execution unit/ SM are limited by the hardware resources. Let me take example of Intel Gen8 GPU. It contains 16 barrier registers per sub slice. So no more than 16 work groups can run simultaneously.

Also, The amount of shared local memory available per sub-slice (64KB). If for example a work-group requires 32KB of shared local memory, only 2 of those work-groups can run concurrently, regardless of work-group size.

Answer (score -1):

I typically use the number of compute units as the number of work groups. I like to scale up the size of the groups to saturate the hardware, rather than force the gpu to schedule many work groups 'simultaneously'.

I don't know of a way to determine the max number of groups without looking it up on the vendor specs.

Comment: I could not find the max number of workgroups from any vendor documentation(AMD,Intel), I don't think there is anything like Max number of work groups, the number of workgroups is limited only by the number of work items, so if you are work items are 1024, then `1024/CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` determines no of workgroups.

Comment: That's not quite the case. When you use clEnqueueNDRangeKernel, you give a local_work_size parameter. This is the work group size (and dimensions). You also specify global_work_size, which is the global size and dimensions. Assuming a 1-D layout The number of work groups is global_work_size/local_work_size. The original question was asking how to find out the limit of concurrent work groups 'in flight' on a gpu. There may be no such limit in theory, but in practice the cache and register swapping dramatically affect performance past some number of groups. It is impossible at some other point.

Comment: If you use this method, it would not give you a guarantee on full occupancy on the device.  Also I would not like to limit the number of workgroups that can be launched from the host.

Comment: @ocluser This is not guaranteed to work.  Certain NVIDIA cards (Fermi architectures) allow a maximum of 1024 work-items per workgroup, but allow 1536 threads to run on a compute unit.  Therefore if I have 512, then your method would yield 2 workgroups per compute unit, when in reality it is 3.